# Why I get Ecto.ConstraintError?

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

Although I call the unique_constraint/3 at the changeset as:

```
  def changeset(parent, params \\ %{}) do
    parent
    |> cast(params, [:created_at , :parent_type , :mobile_number])
    |> unique_constraint(:mobile_number, name: :parents_mobile_number_uindex)

  end
```

I still get error when I do `Repo.update!` or `Repo.update` :

```
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to update struct:

    * unique: parents_mobile_number_uindex

If you would like to convert this constraint into an error, please
call unique_constraint/3 in your changeset and define the proper
constraint name. The changeset has not defined any constraint.

        (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:493: anonymous fn/4 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.constraints_to_errors/3
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1229: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
        (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:479: Ecto.Repo.Schema.constraints_to_errors/3
        (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:284: anonymous fn/13 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_update/4
        (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:142: Ecto.Repo.Schema.update!/4
        (myapp) web/controllers/csvs_controller.ex:484: Myapp.CsvsController.parent_insert_or_update/2
        (myapp) web/controllers/csvs_controller.ex:266: anonymous fn/6 in Myapp.CsvsController.write_ecto_rows_schools/6
        (myapp) web/controllers/csvs_controller.ex:219: Myapp.CsvsController.write_ecto_rows_schools/6
        (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:85: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
        (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:36: Task.Supervised.reply/5
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Any idea?

EDIT:

I already have the constraint in the DB:
[image]

EDIT2:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The **Ecto.ConstraintError** occurred most likely due to the incorrect constraint name based on your error message. ***"The changeset has not defined any constraint."***

You passed an explicit index name into unique_constraint. So the ecto will look for unique index "parents_mobile_number_uindex"

```
create unique_index(:parents, [:mobile_number])
# geneated a unique index "parents_mobile_number_index"
```

Two things to look at:

1. make sure that unique index name is correct:

   ```
   ## at your migration file
   create unique_index(:parents, [:mobile_number], name: : parents_mobile_number_uindex)

   ## at your schema module.
   def changeset(parent, params \\ %{}) do
       parent
       |> cast(params, [:created_at , :parent_type , :mobile_number])
       |> unique_constraint(:mobile_number, name: : parents_mobile_number_uindex)
   end
   ```
2. make sure that you did call the unique_constraint/3 function:

   ```
   parent |> Parent.changeset(%{mobile_number: parent_model.mobile_number}) |> Repo.update()
   # or
   parent |> Ecto.Changeset.change(mobile_number: parent_model.mobile_number) |> unique_constraint(:mobile_number, name: :parents_mobile_number_uindex) |> Repo.update()
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but the constraint already in the DB, please check the edit above

Comment: interesting. could you show me the code around "web/controllers/csvs_controller.ex:484"

Comment: Kindly check EDIT2 above

Comment: Look at line 482, "Ecto.Changeset.change".
you are not using your own changeset function with unique_constraint.

Comment: What about it? looks fine?

Comment: change to something like: changeset =  parent |> Parent.changeset(%{mobile_number: somevalue})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152727/discussion-between-jccf091-and-simo).